# Google Charts: compound chart with column and line chart

Tags: javascript, visualization, google-visualization

I'd like to draw a compound Google Chart with a column chart and line chart.

I've read the [docs on compound charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html), but the examples are all for bar charts using GET options in URLs.

My chart is a [column chart, built using the full Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart.html) - not a bar chart using GET options.

Does anyone know if it's possible to add compound charts to a column chart?

If so, please could you give an example of doing it with the Visualization API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Combo Chart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

It uses the API and allows a combination of line, area, bars/columns, stepped area, and candlestick series on the same chart.